# Java - Acessing global variables & Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, global-variables

I have a simple question regarding how to access global variables and global array information which I have had no luck.

I have two Java files, but can't access the string and array information in my application `Optrader.java`.

1. Optrader.java
2. OptraderGlobals

My OptraderGlobal.java file:

```
 class OptraderGlobal
 {
    String[] columnNames
           = {"Ex-Date",
              "Dividend",
              "Actual",
              "Yield (%)"
             };

  Object[][] data  = {
       {"dd/mm/yyyy", new Double(5), new Boolean(false), 
          {"21/12/2013", new Double(5), new Boolean(false)};
       }
}
```

My Optrader.java file:

```
/* Volatility Table Model is  CLASS within Optrader.java */
//Create Volatility Table
class VolatilityTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
   public int getColumnCount()
   {
         return OptraderGlobal.columnNames1.length;
    }   
 }
```

error:

```
 non-static variable columnNames cannot be
 referenced from a static context
 return OptraderGlobal.columnNames.length;
```

Also I need to access the global array data within other classes in Optrader.java.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the fields to be global, you need to declare them static:

```
static String[] columnNames = ...

static Object[][] data = ...
```

Without the `static` keyword, the fields belong to *instances* of `OptraderGlobal` and not to the class itself.

Comment: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method setText(java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.Object
             VolatilityTableModel.data[0][0].setText(TextLine);

Comment: `Object` has no member `setText`.  You will have to cast the result to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

Make columnNames static.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to be global to a class, you need to declare it as `static`.  This means that the field is associated with the class itself (only one copy), rather than a new version being created for each instance.

Since you didn't do this at present, you ended up with the error copied in your VolatilityTableModel - you can't reference the field without some *particular* instance of OptraderGlobal.

I would suggest that you take a look at some resources dealing with [Object oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) - both this mistake, and your design as a whole (i.e. globals are generally a bad idea), indicate perhaps a lack of familiarity with these principles.  Since Java is an object-oriented language, becoming familiar with this style will help you no end.

Comment: Many thanks for your advise, so better to make an instance of Volatatility table model in the class I want to acess the variable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare them as `public static` to access them the way you want.

```
public static String[] columnNames
           = {"Ex-Date",
              "Dividend",
              "Actual",
              "Yield (%)"
             };

public static Object[][] data  = {
       {"dd/mm/yyyy", new Double(5), new Boolean(false), 
                 {"21/12/2013", new Double(5), new Boolean(false)};
                     }
```

You should declare the classes as public as well.

Comment: Technically, they don't need to be `public` so long as all the accessing classes are within the same package.  (And it looks like everything's in the default package).  While I agree with you that these *should* be public and non-default packages *should* be used, there also *shouldn't* be global/static variables so I guess it's varying levels of moot. :-)

Comment: @Andr, you are correct.  It doesn't need to be public, but, for them to truly be global, they need to be public.

Comment: Hiya,Thanks for the help but it is still saying... cannot find symbol symbol : method setText(java.lang.String) location: class java.lang.Object DividendsTableModel.data[0][0].setText(TextLine); Not sure what to do now regards Stephen

Comment: @Stephen, `data` is an `Object` array.  It doesn't have the method `setText()`.  You probably don't want to be using an `Object[][]` in this case.  But without more information it is hard to say.

Comment: Yes thanks you're right. These are table values that I write to a file say x.dat I open the file and i want to read the data back into the data array - what do I use the object data[][] has no setText() property? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn more about [member fields in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

In your case if you want them just accessible from other classes without creating an instance of `OptTraderGlobal`, you have to make `columnNames` and `data` `static`.

Comment: Hiya still have problems as it is saying

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a new instance of `OptraderGlobal`, or declare the `columnNames` variable as `static`.

It appears you are trying to access it in a static contex

```java
static String[] columnNames = { "Ex-Date", "Dividend", "Actual", "Yield (%)" };
```